# What is a DOMString really?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I came across `DOMString` while reading the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/). On some research, found the following data regarding it:

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMString):

> DOMString is a UTF-16 String. As JavaScript already uses such strings,
>   DOMString is mapped directly to a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

From [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#DOMString):

> A [DOMString](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#DOMString) is a sequence of [16-bit units](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/glossary.html#dt-16-bit-unit).

But I still have the following questions:

1. What is a `DOMString` actually and what is it used for?
2. Why is it named as **DOM**String and not **UTF16**String? More specifically, how does it relate to DOM?
3. If I UTF-16 encode a `String`, does it become a `DOMString`?

Comment: For the purposes of HTML5, the definition of DOMString is deferred to the Web IDL spec (not the DOM spec). DOMString is almost a UTF-16 String, but not quite. In fact the [Web IDL spec says](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-DOMString) "Nothing in this specification requires a DOMString value to be a valid UTF-16 string. For example, a DOMString value might include unmatched surrogate pair characters".

Comment: In the context of this question I would like to add that while `DOMString` is just a regular string in Javascript [`DOMStringList` (link to spec)](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#DOMStringList) is not an array of strings. I've seen this error made for example in some [Flow](https://flow.org/) type definitions.

Comment: @Alohci But isn't it safe to say that any UTF-16 string that contains unmatched surrogate pairs is not valid UTF-16, and therefore not a UTF-16 string in the first place? Usually we think of a *"string"* as an array of *"characters"*. And if we're talking about UTF-16, it is an array of UInt16 values (in the same way a UTF-8 string is an array of UInt8 values). But one of the requirements of UTF-16 (and UTF-8) when encoding some unicode characters is to encode them properly using UTF-16 (or UTF-8) encoding rules. Just because you call your ISO 8859-1 encoded string UTF-8 doesn't mean it is.

Comment: @IanBoyd - Yes exactly. Such an array of UInt16 values would not, per se, be a UTF-16 string, but it _would_ be a DOMString. Hence the need for HTML5 and Web IDL to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's an implementation-independent DOM interface for UTF-16 strings.

JavaScript strings are already UTF-16 strings, so any instance of a JavaScript `String` is automatically also a `DOMString` instance.

The interface is meant for implementations whose strings are not natively UTF-16 sequences, so they can implement a separate type to map to `DOMString` if necessary. The reason an implementation-independent interface is necessary is, as the spec states, "[to] ensure interoperability".

Why is it called `DOMString`? Presumably because it's related to the DOM. How does it relate to the DOM? Well, it's part of the DOM standard, for one.

Comment: [Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-C74D1578) to be precise.

Comment: UTF-16 in this context is UCS-2, isn't it? Because there are no surrogate pairs (lead and trail), but only 16-bit (2 bytes) code units.

Comment: I am just as confused after reading this as I was before visiting.  I need to see some code examples. Can someone please explain it in a way that even a 5 year old could understand? Please?

Comment: ["It's an implementation-independent DOM interface for UTF-16 strings."] - Lots of big words that don't say much.

Comment: ["JavaScript strings are already UTF-16 strings, so any instance of a JavaScript String is automatically also a DOMString instance."] - So what you are telling me here is that DOMstrings are essentially the same as normal strings?

Comment: ["The interface is meant for implementations that...states, "[to] ensure interoperability"."] - I can barely understand what you are saying in this bit. Something to do with `DOMstring` being more lenient than regular strings I think but I have no context of "this is what you can do with `DOMstring` that you cannot do with regular strings. I have no context at the moment for why `DOMstring` is a thing that needed to exist.

Comment: @Daniel Tonon: Yes, any String is also a DOMString and vice versa, if that's all you want to know. The rest of it is exposition for why DOMString exists as a separate interface - for example, some other language might want to implement this but its strings are limited to UTF-8. DOMString will provide a guaranteed UTF-16 implementation. If all you're writing is JavaScript, you don't need to know this.

Comment: @DanielTonon "*DOMstrings are essentially the same as normal strings?*" - yes, but only if you come from JavaScript where there's only one string type and that's the "normal" one to you.

Answer (score 2):

Taking as example 3 different ways to use [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

> Element.append() allows you to also append DOMString objects

Those 3 elements are both [DOMString(s)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)

```js
document.body.append(

  Object.assign(document.createElement("h2"), {textContent: "Hello"}),
  
  new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<span> world</span>`, "text/html").body.firstChild,
 
 "!"
 
)
```

```css
H2, SPAN {display:inline; FONT-SIZE: X-LARGE}
```